# Add validations to peewee model in flask

Tags: python, flask, peewee, flask-restful

I'm building an api with flask and sqlite/peewee and I'd like to add constraints to a model.

I have a model Fruit:

```
class Fruit(Model):
  name = CharField(unique=True)
  color = CharField()
  created_at =DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

I want to add constraints like minimum and maximum length, valid characters, etc.
Looking at the peewee docs, all I found was a max_length parameter accepted by CharField, but what if I want to add other, more specific constraints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Went through the code of Peewee, validation is not supported by peewee. The max_length CharField accepts, is a modifier which applied to SQL. Also it applied to the value with:

```
self.value = self.value[:self.max_length]
```

But that is not validation.

So you can write your own validtion layer on top of peewee models. Or use a validtor library like: [schematics](https://schematics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
>>> # Copied from schematics document
>>> from schematics.models import Model
>>> from schematics.types import StringType, URLType
>>> class Person(Model):
...     name = StringType(required=True)
...     website = URLType()

>>> person = Person()
>>> person.website = 'http://www.amontobin.com/'
>>> person.validate()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "schematics/models.py", line 231, in validate
    raise DataError(e.messages)
schematics.exceptions.DataError: {'name': ['This field is required.']}
```